# Why are my overridden methods returning False?

Tags: python, dictionary, operator-overloading

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, the fix was to `return fnc(*args)` from `wrapper`.

I am creating a custom dictionary-like class that supports some extra QoL features for measurements I take.

```py
class MeasurementDataset:
    def __init__(self):
        self._dict = dict()

    @staticmethod
    def hash_input(fnc):
        def wrapper(*args):
            args = list(args)
            if not isinstance(args[1], str):
                args[1] = tuple(args[1])
            fnc(*args)

        return wrapper

    @hash_input
    def __contains__(self, key):
        print(f"internal check: {key in self._dict}")
        return key in self._dict

    @hash_input
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print(f"internal check: {self._dict[key]}")
        return self._dict[key]

    @hash_input
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._dict[key] = value
```

I would expect it to function like a dictionary with this simple code. However, even though my dunder methods seem to be evaluating correctly internally, I am getting incorrect output.

```py
In [3]: d = MeasurementDataset()

In [5]: key = (1, 2, 3, 4)

In [6]: value = f.measure(key)

In [15]: value
Out[15]: Measurement(cf=156.37, bw=35.84, loss=5.59)

In [7]: d[key] = value

In [12]: key in d
internal check: True
Out[12]: False

In [14]: print(d[key])
internal check: Measurement(cf=156.37, bw=35.84, loss=5.59)
None
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you think `wrapper` returns?

Comment: Thank you, the fix was indeed to `return fnc(*args)` from `wrapper`. It's always something so simple!